# Can I just T into a CAN bus network if I just want to observe the data?

Tags: can

Can I just T into a CAN bus network if I simply want to snoop on the data flowing?

I know I have to disable ACK bit sending, but is it just a case of physically splicing into CAN-High and CAN-Low?

Comment: Well, ideally you should match the impedance and terminate the line properly... But it will work most likely without it.

Comment: Will work for short wires. Just do it nicely, quick and dirty may interfere with the whole bus.

Comment: Please, describe what is your understanding of "Tee" in this particular case. Many people, especially newcomers may find it unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with some restrictions.  The typical differential twisted pair CAN implementation tries to keep the impedance of the transmission line to 120 Ω.  Anything that deviates from that, like a T connection, will cause some reflection of signals.

In practise, keep the T short and it should be fine.  The Transceiver chip, like the common Microchip MCP2551, should be only at most a few inches from the line you are tapping into.  The higher the CAN bitrate, the more keeping the Ts short matters.

Comment: Good info,  it'll be on a workbench so distance shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the standard there are two requirements with respect to Ts:

- A limit to the total length of Ts
- A limit for the length of each T

The first limit is on the order of a few meters and the second is on the order of 0.5 meters, so you will probably be well within specs. Even with long Ts it will probably work well anyway - on my test setup I currently, to challenge the system, have a 5 meter T on a 50 meter CAN bus and don't get any error frames over a 24-hour period (250 kbit/s speed with approximately 25% bus load, about 5 x 10<sup>9</sup> bits). Reflections are easily seen on an oscilloscope, but they die down long before the sampling point (approximately midpoint in a bit time).

Most CAN adapters support a mode where the adapter does not participate on the CAN bus by asserting ACK (for instance, called "listen" or "passive" mode). But even if it *does* participate it usually does not make a difference.

So yes, sniffing is easy, without causing any heisenbugs.

Comment: I will provide more accurate numbers later when I have found the relevant parts of the standard.

Comment: [TI Document SLLA270](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla270/slla270.pdf) indicates 1.6m unterminated stub for a 50ns driver transmission time, but if you can slew rate limit to 160ns, 5.3m.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your measurements/observations from your test setup, it's always good to have 'real' data